# Unable to apt install armhf packages with unmet dependencies

Tags: apt, gstreamer, multiarch

I am trying to setup an multi arch environment to cross compile armhf board.
The steps I followed is quite simple.

1. Install ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64 on VirtualBox.
2. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf`
3. `vim /etc/apt/sources.list` and add followings.

```
deb [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ trusty main universe     
deb-src [arch=armhf] http://ports.ubuntu.com/ trusty main universe
[And put [arch=i386,amd64] for the other lines.]
```

4. `sudo apt update`
5. `sudo apt install libgstreamer1.0-dev:armhf`

And the installation was unsuccessful with following error.

```
sudo apt install libgstreamer1.0-dev:armhf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgstreamer1.0-dev:armhf : Depends: libgstreamer1.0-0:armhf (= 1.14.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: libc6-dev:armhf but it is not going to be installed or
                                      libc-dev:armhf
                             Depends: libglib2.0-dev:armhf but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: libc6:armhf (>= 2.4) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: libglib2.0-0:armhf (>= 2.40) but it is not going to be installed
                             Depends: gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:armhf (= 1.14.0-1) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I've some searching and tried following things and didn't help.

1. `sudo apt -f install`
2. Tried install missing dependant package manually but it's recursive. I mean, if I do `sudo apt install gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0:armhf`, it fails with unmet dependency of `libgstreamer1.0-0:armhf`

Any advice will be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think your software needs an update.

- first, run the below commands to upgrade the Ubuntu system.

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

- Problem still?

you need to install the latest version of [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?version=20.04.1&architecture=amd64)

Comment: Actually I tried 20.04 first and it didn't work. So I am trying to lower the version to 18.04. 
I still having the problem after `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

For those of you facing the same problem, I would suggest to use Debian for armhf cross compiling. It just worked nicely.

1. Debian 10.7.0-amd64 on VirtualBox
2. `sudo dpkg --add-architecture armhf`
3. `sudo apt update`
4. `sudo apt install libgstreamer1.0-dev:armhf` works.

Example: https://github.com/kwoolytech/AmazonKinesisProducerCpp